# How to create a file from string and send it via FormData

Tags: node.js, buffer, fs, node-streams

I have a *svg* in form of a string. I want to convert that string into a file and send it via `FormData` to another API.

I found a way how it works but that includes creating a file locally (with `fs`) and then creating a `readStream` from the just created file. Processing many files this is super slow and ends in a timout most of the time.

```
fs.writeFile('file.svg', svgString, async () => {
            const fr = fs.createReadStream('file.svg');
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('media', fr);

            const response = await Axios.post(route, formData, {...}
            });
        });
```

Here is my (failing) approach using Buffer and Readable:

```
// Create readable from svg string
const b = Buffer.from(svgString, 'utf-8');
const r = Readable.from(b);

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('media', fr);

const response = await Axios.post(route, formData, {...});
```

This method is not giving the same result as the first.
I then get a error from the external API.

The question is how do I get the same result as in the first approach, without writing local files to the disk.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the problem was less the buffer than the form data.

The API required the data to have a filename, which it automatically had when read from an actual file with `fs.createReadStream('file.svg');`

So when creating a Buffer I had to add it manually.
So final working solution is:

```
const svgBuffer = Buffer.from(svgString);
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('media', svgBuffer, {
    filename: 'content.svg'
});
```

Comment: It is not working for pdf. Do you have any solution for that? the buffer data of pdf creates empty pdf on the other end.

Comment: Are you also creating the buffer from a string?

Comment: I am using busboy. It reads the received file content and then I try to append in form data  to send another api endpoint.

Comment: Busboy reading of received pdf file is having more bytes than original pdf file. Here is the link of the screenshot. Do you have any idea on this? https://im.ge/i/QSWxNp

Comment: I am using netlify function. See -> https://answers.netlify.com/t/trouble-with-handling-files-in-netlify-function/42418